Is it possible to create a Bose-Einstein condensate of ions?
The question is in the title. In my opinion, it can not be created, as ions have Coloumb interaction, while condensate is usually created from weakly interacting particles. However, some condensates have been created using dipolar quantum gases with rather strong dipole-dipole interactions as well. So I am a little confused about whether it would be possible to create a BEC of ions.
Any comments or details?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_crystal Ions crystallize similarly already at higher density.
